# Excel Search Formula only works for exact match

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the search formula in Excel to check whether a column contains a string. However, I don't need the match to be exact. So f.i., if a cell in the column has abcd in it and while I'm searching for abc, I still want a value returned. Unfortunately at the moment I only get a value returned if I search for abcd exactly.

The formula I use right now looks like this:

```
  =SEARCH("abc";A2:A8)
```

There's no value returned, even though A3 has "abcd" in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you're trying to search a _range_ of cells rather than a _single_ cell. You either need to use an array formula, or use `=MATCH()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I normally don't like to provide a link for an answer...  But I had to do this EXACT same thing a few weeks ago, and held on to the link that gave me the answer:

[Contains in Excel](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text)

In short, it uses a method of checking a result being a number if the substring exists.  Seems like a strange approach, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Use *MATCH()* with a wildcard:

```
=MATCH("*abc*",A2:A8,0)
```

[image]